# How to scrape glassdoor Company Overview

Tags: python, python-requests, screen-scraping

```
import requests
import json
headers = {'User-Agent': '1.Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0',
          'Accept': 'application/json'
          }
url = 'https://www.glassdoor.com/Job/didcot-england-junior-software-developer-jobs-SRCH_IL.0,14_IC3380446_KO15,40.htm?src=GD_JOB_AD&srs=ALL_RESULTS&jl=1007788802873&ao=1136043&s=345&guid=000001805a9ddcf09055e561485879b6&pos=101&t=SR-JOBS-HR&vt=w&uido=47F765FE71E439F398E8E149B3F8C23F&ea=1&cs=1_e20b1a86&cb=1650787737088&jobListingId=1007788802873&jrtk=3-0-1g1d9rn8pjm5g801-1g1d9rn9ipker800-bed2bb63e14539cd-'
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
```

I'm trying to get companies url from the site, I know that glassdoor has it's own api, but I can't get API credentials  to access them. So I'm trying to do it manually but still without any results, who can help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing it by using their API (which probably needs authentication), you can get the info from automatized DOM analysis. There are many tools for that and you can even write your own tool. I particularly like [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/).